# Proof by direct method?

Tags: proof-verification

> **Definition:** An integer $n$ is *throdd* if $n=3k+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.
>
> **Proposition:** For all integers $n$, if $n^2$ is throdd, then $n$ is throdd.

**direct proof:**

let $n$ be a particular but arbitrarily chosen throdd integer

then $n = 3k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

then $n^2 = (3k + 1)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1 = 3(3k^2 + 2k) + 1$

$3k^2 + 2k$ is an integer by closure, $n^2$ meets the definition of threeven.

Wouldn't there be a counter example, or is there a way to prove it by contrapositive?

Comment: "throdd" is not a standard mathematical term.  I think you mean "not divisible by $3$".

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think it is $3k+1$, and threevens are $3k+2$. I hope we won't have elevenevens or stuff like that in the future.

Comment: And I have no idea what "PBAC" is supposed to mean.

Comment: If it is $3k+1$, the statement is wrong: e.g. consider $2^2$.

Comment: Unless the teacher has defined the term and said definition is included here, this will probably be closed as "unclear what you're asking". Don't worry, though; it can always be reopened once you've figured that out.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, maybe it's related to PEBKAC (problem exists between keyboard and chair).

Comment: From your post: what's a PBAC?

Comment: A *throdd integer* is an integer of the form $3k+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, as John’s [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541963/prove-m-3k1-quad-m-k-in-mathbb-z-implies-m2-3l1-quad-m-l-in-mathbb-z). PBAC is *particular but arbitrarily chosen*.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t start by assuming that $n$ is throdd: that’s what you’re trying to prove, so any such argument would be circular. For a direct proof you should assume that $n^2$ is throdd, and for a proof of the contrapositive you should assume that $n$ is **not** throdd and try to prove that $n^2$ is not throdd. That looks more promising, so you might try it. If $n$ is not throdd, then $n$ is not $3k+1$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$, and therefore either $n=3k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, or $n=3k+2$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. If $n=3k$, then $n^2=(3k)^2=9k^2=3(3k^2)$, so $n^2$ is not throdd, just as we hoped to find.

Now investigate what happens if $n=3k+2$. Is $n^2$ always throdd? Never throdd? Sometimes throdd and sometimes not? If it’s never throdd, you’ve proved the proposition; in either of the other two cases you can find a counterexample to show that the proposition isn’t always true.